# Why don't blocks that use % properties and add up to 100% not go side-by-side?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make two blocks fit side-by-side within another block, but I'm confused as to why they don't sit nicely next to each other?

```
.container {height: 200px; width: 400px; background:darkgrey;}
.left {height: 100%; width: 49.8%; margin: 0 0.2%; background:blue; float:left;}
.right {background:red; height:100%; width: 50%; float:left;}
```

IF i make the margin 0.1%, it works but doesn't align perfectly on the right side.

Why doesn't that work, am I missing something?

http://jsfiddle.net/hyZhU/

Using latest Chrome.

Comment: Your `0.2%` margin is applied to both left and right... taking up `.4%` of the container's width... [change it to `0.1%`](http://jsfiddle.net/antisanity/hyZhU/3/) or [adjust your child width to `49.6%`](http://jsfiddle.net/antisanity/hyZhU/5/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`margin` and `padding` are additional to the width.

e.g., if you have `width: 100px; margin: 10px; padding: 15px;`, the actual width of the element will be 150px

Since you have `width: 49.8%; margin: 0 0.2%;`, that totals `50.2%`+padding for each element. I lowered the width to `49.6%` and specified `padding: 0`. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hyZhU/4/

Comment: I get that, but 49.8% block 1 + margin 0.2% + block 2 of 50% = 100%?

Comment: @user2413333 Specify `padding: 0` and half the margin to `0.1%`, as it is doubled, once for each left and right.

Answer (score 2):

The `.02%` margin is applied to *both* sides (the left and the right) so the first block actually has a total width of `50.2%`.  Use `.01%` for the margin instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/hyZhU/1/

Answer (score 1):

When you use set the `margin` property with two you values, you're setting both the top and bottom margins equal to the first value, then the left and right margins equal to the second. Because of this, your left box has takes up space equivalent 0.2% (left margin) + 49.8% (actual width) + 0.2% (right margin), which adds up to 50.2%. This causes the second box to be pushed onto a new line.

Answer (score 0):

This should work,,

```
.container {height: 200px; width: 400px; background:darkgrey;}
    .left {height: 100%; width: 45%; margin: 0 0.2%; background:blue; float:left;}
    .right {background:red; height:100%; width: 45%; float:right;}
```

UPDATE

```
.container {height: 200px; width: 400px; background:darkgrey;}
    .left {height: 100%; width: 199px; margin: 0 1px; background:blue; float:left;}
    .right {background:red; height:100%; width: 199px; float:right;}
```

Comment: It works...but it doesn't add up to 100%, meaning it doesn't really solve the problem. Either `width` should be `49.6%`, or `margin` should be `0 0.1%`.

Comment: I have updated the code, your should check it out.. I have not used % but actual px values.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers have to translate the percentages into pixels, and different browsers add up those percentages differently. So 49.8% of the current width may be rounded up by one browser to 201px, and down to 199px by another.

That means that after being adjusted into pixels, the browser may be trying to fit content that's greater than 100% into the space, which causes the wrapping.

The best way to avoid this is to use longer percentage values to minimize rounding, and/or to combine border-box (http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) into your solution as well.

For example: 33.3333333% is better than 33.3%.

Comment: I also realize I haven't given you a specific answer to your specific question, but rather a conceptual framework to base your design adjustments on.

Comment: thanks for that Chris, the problem is definitely around here somewhere, the fiddle I made had a typo (margin:0 0.2% instead of 0 0.2% 0 0). In my real example it isn't that, if i set one width to 49.79 and the margin to 0.21, they fit side by side but there is a tiny margin on the right of the second block. If I set it to 47.911111 and margin 0.211111 they don't float side by side anymore....... Very frustrating!

Comment: Not to be the guy that just pushes his own stuff, but you might find it helpful to dig around the grid I use in my Kraken boilerplate (http://cferdinandi.github.io/kraken/), which is based on Foldy960 by Dave Rupert (https://github.com/davatron5000/Foldy960). I sometimes find that deconstructing a working design helps me wrap my head around how stuff works.